# Why is my image not showing up after UV unwrapping?

Tags: uv

I'm following a YouTube tutorial on UV unwrapping the image of a mouth onto a character ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY ), and although I've followed all the steps, several times, to a T, I cannot get the mouth image to show up on the character. I've included the blend file for your convenience. Could you please help me understand why this is not working?

Steps that I took:

1. Mark the seam.
2. Unwrap the faces.
3. Open the png mouth image.
4. Create a new material that is a copy of the material used for the body.
5. Add an image texture to that material.
6. Assign the new material.
   When I use the file that he provides to go along with, the results are as expected. But when I do the same thing to my file, I do not get the same results.

Please, if you could take some time to help me I would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Here is a copy of my file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JxxWnnUfpxqWwv0Fo_5trLo4L7luAJq-

A copy of his file:

[image]

The png file used for unwrapping: [image: PNG file used for UV Unwrapping]

[image: UV Unwrapping problem - Image not showing up]

Comment: Did you **assign** the material to the faces of the object? Also, materials do not show in solid shading, use **material** or **rendered shading**... See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html?highlight=solid%20shading

Comment: I'm such a dummy! I was in the solid shading the whole time! I forget these little things some times. It's all a lot to take in, keep track of and remember. That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materials do not show in solid shading.

Switch to **material** or **rendered** shading.

[image]

> **Bounding Box**.
>
> Only shows rectangular boxes that outline an object’s size and shape.
>
> **Wireframe**
>
> Objects appear as a mesh of lines representing the edges of faces and surfaces.
>
> **Solid**
>
> The default drawing mode using solid colored surfaces and simple lighting.
>
> **Textured**
>
> Shows meshes with an image applied using the mesh’s active UV Map. For Cycles materials, the image is the last one selected in the Node Editor. For other render engines, the UV Map’s applied face texture will be shown.
>
> **Material**
>
> A fast approximation of the applied material.
>
> **Rendered**
>
> An accurate representation using the selected Render Engine and lit with the visible scene lights.

For more info please refer to the blender manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you possibly tried applying the texture to the material AND texture tab? How about with the same texture? One way to make sure you have the right texture is to, instead of reopening a file, just select the same file by clicking the arrow next to it. Hope this helps, sorry for not being a teensy bit more specific.